# Serialized body (Protobuf?)

Tags: decompress

There is an application on iOS that collects data and encrypts it in the future. Data is already serialized at entry to the encryption function, they look like this(I tried to decode, restore the scheme, but nothing comes out, I hope for the help of experienced people):
[image]
Or like this:
[image]

**First HEX**:

> 01 61 11 00 35 32 31 2e 33 34 36 35 32 33 01 62 11 00 31 32 2e 36 35
> 37 33 34 34 01 63 11 00 31 35 37 2e 35 36 33 34 36 37 01 64 a4 03 4d
> 56 39 35 6a 68 39 4a 56 4e 01 65 24 00 42 43 32 41 35 39 38 36 2d 34
> 43 37 45 2d 34 46 35 31 2d 38 46 32 30 2d 30 36 37 45 46 35 44 42 43
> 32 37 34 01 66 04 00 6f c6 52 64 01 67 00 00 01 68 04 00 bc 60 32 36

**Second HEX**:

> 01 61 12 00 37 37 2e 36 37 31 37 37 39 35 34 36 35 36 35 39 31 35 01
> 62 11 00 39 31 2e 31 36 36 32 31 30 36 32 34 30 38 39 31 35 01 63 05
> 00 31 35 36 2e 30 01 64 0c 00 d0 a0 d0 be d1 81 d1 81 d0 b8 d1 8f 01
> 65 1d 00 d0 9a d1 83 d1 80 d1 81 d0 ba d0 b0 d1 8f 20 d0 be d0 b1 d0
> bb d0 b0 d1 81 d1 82 d1 8c 01 66 04 00 2d 31 2e 30 01 67 24 00 42 31
> 32 42 38 36 32 38 2d 38 30 39 41 2d 34 41 35 35 2d 39 30 42 39 2d 39
> 46 44 46 45 41 34 36 36 30 32 33 01 68 04 00 57 69 46 69 01 6a 04 00
> 63 0a 53 64 01 6c 01 00 00 01 6d 01 00 00 01 6e a4 03 41 6b 34 41 41
> 77 41 30 41 41 45 34 45 4e 76 62 37 34 33 56 45 56 36 4e 53 4f 61 6d
> 4b 64 57 37 4d 2b 30 4e 4b 55 6c 67 4e 6c 67 6b 79 64 51 67 42 55 56
> 5a 4b 35 31 50 4f 57 53 64 54 2f 51 68 49 49 4c 32 54 4e 64 6a 32 36
> 42 2b 61 47 2b 55 79 74 63 6a 6d 39 41 65 57 7a 6e 64 67 52 57 4f 77
> 77 44 44 33 46 51 74 55 47 73 54 75 6e 39 33 38 79 57 71 36 43 34 52
> 44 46 68 6a 30 44 71 33 6d 4b 35 4d 35 37 64 69 61 43 6d 46 44 61 37
> 78 53 72 5a 65 78 61 37 49 53 78 7a 32 50 6c 6a 69 38 65 2f 34 64 4c
> 43 46 7a 37 6a 65 79 32 62 70 58 62 46 2f 6d 79 6f 63 38 4b 75 57 70
> 32 5a 6f 76 38 47 4b 2b 62 55 72 39 5a 6e 75 68 71 45 42 64 6a 6e 4f
> 30 79 52 57 4e 2b 70 2b 68 53 4f 45 72 37 77 41 4b 2f 6f 51 2f 41 6e
> 55 50 75 4b 68 63 47 6b 63 62 4f 30 7a 59 70 53 54 69 6a 52 43 44 76
> 4f 7a 35 79 49 72 30 71 74 61 32 50 38 41 54 56 69 4d 6b 70 5a 32 45
> 79 78 59 67 30 67 36 54 55 75 57 51 79 6e 6c 52 33 62 4e 70 6c 7a 53
> 4f 62 43 69 74 6d 4e 38 69 32 73 66 76 63 68 4d 34 51 65 5a 67 66 76
> 70 4e 4f 52 56 6f 52 51 51 35 49 70 38 65 50 55 38 35 43 6c 68 62 45
> 38 62 65 37 75 68 58 46 4b 43 4a 70 47 31 36 41 68 42 63 65 2b 79 67
> 46 50 36 6d 6e 38 46 47 36 41 42 6e 59 4c 58 4e 64 61 45 6f 4c 64 43
> 67 49 78 41 52 42 4d 48 49 76 6d 69 45 34 59 58 5a 33 5a 77 52 53 63
> 33 63 79 53 36 31 54 55 51 4b 36 5a 73 78 57 77 41 76 36 53 36 6a 52
> 55 76 39 2f 31 31 64 33 72 54 30 48 66 77 4b 7a 35 42 47 41 78 55 56
> 41 75 76 62 71 67 58 59 7a 35 33 61 38 4b 74 68 67 6b 53 67 2f 66 71
> 43 54 34 68 48 63 44 33 76 39 53 6c 42 6b 61 37 38 51 4b 68 64 39 4b
> 6a 5a 64 6b 78 33 7a 57 43 38 6f 4b 77 39 67 54 32 6c 35 51 77 46 47
> 74 53 66 51 71 30 6a 73 59 75 59 54 6a 38 70 56 43 56 34 39 6e 4c 79
> 53 52 57 46 53 34 4d 41 4f 47 62 76 73 39 63 73 54 38 39 6c 59 36 50
> 4b 5a 7a 33 31 7a 34 56 59 38 4f 31 54 32 69 6d 58 6f 74 56 77 45 74
> 5a 6b 2b 59 78 68 32 6d 76 76 79 5a 68 79 6a 54 54 77 77 37 7a 6f 52
> 4f 68 56 4c 4e 74 71 6a 49 6e 6f 47 41 33 6e 35 4d 58 4e 4e 45 53 34
> 49 2b 63 35 47 63 79 5a 6a 6b 76 6d 67 33 78 6f 2b 54 7a 4b 4d 75 50
> 4b 75 35 73 4d 48 41 5a 4f 37 33 79 7a 70 6d 79 46 71 6d 31 71 44 4e
> 45 73 54 37 55 39 30 62 74 6c 71 42 64 43 66 50 75 71 33 4d 6b 4c 78
> 61 51 59 43 63 67 74 45 37 74 31 67 33 73 44 5a 6e 59 41 46 70 68 2b
> 53 69 6a 6b 6e 41 65 38 33 61 44 31 68 57 41 78 63 4d 66 41 52 75 43
> 76 6f 36 36 65 34 4b 6c 69 44 6c 49 69 74 55 6b 78 55 4a 42 73 6b 2f
> 4c 38 69 67 67 52 52 4c 45 5a 53 65 47 6c 63 45 36 56 74 61 2b 6e 4f
> 5a 47 63 55 6c 52 59 77 51 53 45 45 63 42 32 33 7a 76 58 6f 5a 34 47
> 75 31 31 55 41 4f 5a 34 4a 70 48 47 61 69 73 37 55 56 64 76 4c 36 6d
> 50 63 4b 30 75 4f 4d 59 56 55 42 6c 59 6a 53 6a 66 56 61 70 30 6d 39
> 4c 6b 2b 4e 2b 67 63 32 79 4b 50 4a 35 4b 53 73 32 34 4c 71 69 4d 69
> 66 56 76 66 49 59 64 38 61 56 77 36 39 59 6e 34 76 53 6d 37 68 4f 6f
> 53 67 72 48 44 49 3d 01 69 04 00 1a f8 e4 b7 01 6b 01 00 30

I need to know how to serialize data like this for reproduce this requests by myself if its possible. Thank you